# Is there a way to draw a matter.js composite with p5?

Tags: p5.js, matter.js

I recently saw the matter.js on the coding train channel from 2017, I've managed to replicate the examples shown on those videos but now I wanted to do something more advanced. There is a Composite module called stack in the [documentation](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Composites.html) used to create a soft body in the matter.js [demos](https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#softBody) but I wonder if there is a way to draw this using p5 instead.

[This](https://editor.p5js.org/gundam43125/sketches/Yx7X4v-ug) is what I've gotten so far, any help is appreciated

Comment: Code should be in the question itself as a [mcve]. Links to offsite resources disappear over time, leaving the question useless to future visitors. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issue with your code was that you weren't adding the `Composite` to the `world`. Here's a working example with a few other tweaks:

```js
const {
  Bodies,
  Common,
  Composites,
  Constraint,
  Engine,
  Runner,
  World
} = Matter;

var engine;
var world;
var particles = [];
var boundaries = [];
var composi1;
var composi2;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  engine = Engine.create();
  world = engine.world;

  // Use a runner to actually run the simulation
  const runner = Runner.create();
  Runner.run(runner, engine);

  // Add two composites so we can see them interact
  composi1 = new softbodi(100, 50, 4, 4, 0, 0, true, 20);
  composi2 = new softbodi(50, 300, 4, 2, 0, 0, true, 20);

  boundaries.push(new Boundary(200, height, width, 50, 0));
}

function draw() {
  background(51);

  for (var i = 0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
    boundaries[i].show();
  }

  composi1.show();
  composi2.show();
}

function softbodi(
  xx,
  yy,
  columns,
  rows,
  columnGap,
  rowGap,
  crossBrace,
  particleRadius) {

  this.r = particleRadius;

  this.composite = Composites.stack(
    xx,
    yy,
    columns,
    rows,
    columnGap,
    rowGap,
    function(x, y) {
      return Bodies.circle(x, y, particleRadius);
    }
  );

  this.mesh = Composites.mesh(this.composite, columns, rows, crossBrace);

  // Dont forget to add you composite to the world
  World.add(world, this.composite);

  this.show = function() {
    var parr = [];
    parr = Matter.Composite.allBodies(this.composite);
    for (var i = 0; i < parr.length; i++) {
      var pos = parr[i].position;
      var angle = parr[i].angle;
      push();
      translate(pos.x, pos.y);
      rotate(angle);
      rectMode(CENTER);
      strokeWeight(1);
      stroke(255);
      fill(127);
      ellipse(0, 0, this.r * 2);
      pop();
    }
  };
}

function Boundary(x, y, w, h, a) {
  var options = {
    friction: 0,
    restitution: 0.95,
    angle: a,
    isStatic: true
  };
  this.body = Bodies.rectangle(x, y, w, h, options);
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  World.add(world, this.body);

  this.show = function() {
    var pos = this.body.position;
    var angle = this.body.angle;
    push();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    rotate(angle);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    strokeWeight(1);
    noStroke();
    fill(0);
    rect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
    pop();
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.17.1/matter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```